# how do i convert SQL query to HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hql

```
public class EmployeeUserMap {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEEID", unique = true)
    protected Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USERID")
    private User user;
}

public class RoleUserMap  {


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLEID")
    private Role role;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERID")
    private User user;


}
```

Below is my SQL query.

```
select e.id ,e.firstname from employee_user_map o
          left join role_user_map ru on ru.userid = o.userid
          left join employee e on e.id = o.employeeid
          where  ru.roleid =  (select r.id from role r  where r.code='Role_Merchant')
```

**HQL query i tried.**

```
 SELECT new com.erp.core.repository.value.LookupValue(o.id,o.firstName,o.firstName) FROM EmployeeUserMap o
            LEFT JOIN o.user =
            WHERE /*@{SYSTEM_CRITERIA}*/1=1 AND (UPPER(o.firstName) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%',:searchParam,'%')))
```

Comment: Your HQL query bares little resemblance to the SQL query.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: No. That is because i decided to go with HQL after writing SQl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your mappings right, you should form the hql query as:

Hibernate version < 5.1.0:

```
  select new   com.erp.core.repository.value.LookupValue(e.id,e.firstName) 
      from EmployeeUserMap eu
         , RoleUserMap ru
         , Employee e
         , User u
         , Role r
      where  r.code ='Role_Merchant'
          and eu.user = u
          and ru.user = u
          and ru.role =r
          and eu.employee = e
```

dont think you really need the subquery here..

**Update**: for version 5.1.0+ of HIbernate it is possible to use unrelated entity joins, so in your case:

```
  select new com.erp.core.repository.value.LookupValue(e.id,e.firstName) 
  from EmployeeUserMap o
    left join o.user u
    left join o.employee e
    left join RoleUserMap ru on ru.user.id = u.id
    left join ru.role r
  where  r.code ='Role_Merchant'
```

Comment: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: roleUserMap of: com.erp.hr.domain.EmployeeUserMap.
EmployeeUserMap and RoleUserMap dont have direct connection , But they have User in common.

Comment: Please adjust the names to your case.. i just guested the entity names in your application

Comment: Thats not the issue.there is no roleUserMap in EmployeeUserMap Please take look at the updated question.

Comment: ok i see, do you have a OneToMany mapping on User to the RoleUserMap ?

Comment: No i have ManyToOne relationship.

Comment: can you add it or it has to remain a uni-directional realtionshiop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162994/discussion-between-boycod3-and-maciej-kowalski).

Comment: what is your hiberntae version?

Comment: Hibernate version  5

Comment: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: firstName of: com.erp.hr.domain.EmployeeUserMap   after using new HQL

Comment: make sure you use LookupValue(e.id,e.firstName) .. not o.firstName

Comment: I have checked it it is e.firstName.

Comment: select new com.erp.core.repository.value.LookupValue(e.id,e.firstName)
  from EmployeeUserMap o
    left join o.user u
    left join o.employee e
    left join RoleUserMap ru on ru.user.id = u.id
    left join ru.role r
  where /*@{SYSTEM_CRITERIA}*/1=1 AND r.code ='Role_Merchant'
  AND (UPPER(e.firstName) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%',:searchParam,'%')))

final query and getting this error    Path expected for join! [

Comment: are you sure you have 5.1.0+ hibernate version?