# Convert from SQL to HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I want to convert this query to HQL syntax please:

```
SELECT count(*) from ( SELECT count(name) as tot FROM myTable WHERE id = 1 GROUP BY name ) as src;
```

**UPDATE**

I found a way to do it : based on [Count the number of groups in HQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827811/count-the-number-of-groups-in-hql-query)

this query `SELECT count(name) as tot FROM myTable WHERE id = 1 GROUP BY name` return me a List and then i do a `.size()`. it works for me !

Comment: SO, is not intended for query conversion. Try to read the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql) at first.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you. refer to it [how do i convert SQL query to HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209762/how-do-i-convert-sql-query-to-hql)

Answer (score 0):

Please ry this:

```
SELECT count(mt) as tot FROM myTable mt WHERE mnt.id = 1
```

Comment: I try it, but its not given me the result i want, however i found a way, look in my Update

Comment: That's great. Best wishes.